# jquery if clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is just a small piece of code of my function. The function is by default false, when you click on the #my-button the function will be true and run.

But now I want that when you click on the same button again, the function will be false again and should stop working.

And that should he be doing every time you click the button (it would be great if this is also possible with classes instead of the id)

```
$('#my-button').toggle(function () {
    sliderPaused = true;
}, function () {
    sliderPaused = false;
});
```

I use a toggle function, only this does not work for me. Is there something wrong at my code?

Comment: `$('#my-button').click(function() {
  sliderPaused = !sliderPaused;
});
`

Comment: [toggle(fn, fn)](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) was removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: Thanks @Arun P Johny it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-button').click(function () {
       if (sliderPaused) sliderPaused = false;
       else sliderPaused = true;
});
```